# React renderiza solo cuando salgo y vuelvo del componente

Tags: reactjs, ordenamiento, redux

mi problema es el siguiente, estoy usando react redux para una sencilla aplicacion que muestra datos del clima. El problema que tengo es que al seleccionar una opcion para que me ordene las tarjetas por orden alfabético puedo ver que el estado global cambio(es decir que se ordena) pero react no renderiza al instante. Sí lo hace cuando, por ejemplo me voy a la seccion about y vuelvo al home, ahí puedo ver las tarjetas ordenadas o atmbién lo hace cuando doy click en el boton home.

````
```import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getCity, sortCards } from "../../Redux/actions";
import Card from "../../Components/Card/Card";
import Filter from "../../Components/Filter/Filter";
import style from "./Home.module.css";

const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const city = useSelector((state) => state.cities);
  // console.log(city);

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredCities(city);
  }, [city, dispatch]);

  const [filteredCities, setFilteredCities] = useState([]);
  console.log(filteredCities);
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const handleInputSearch = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input === "") {
      alert("Ingrese el nombre de la Ciudad");
    } else {
      dispatch(getCity(input));
      setInput("");
    }
  };

  const handleSort = (e) => {
    dispatch(sortCards(e.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <div className={style.body}>
      <Filter
        handleInputSearch={handleInputSearch}
        handleSearch={handleSearch}
        input={input}
        handleSort={handleSort}
      />
      <div className={style.cardcontainer}>
        {filteredCities.map((c) => {
          return (
            <Card
              key={c.location.name}
              name={c.location.name}
              img={c.current.condition.icon}
              condition={c.current.condition.text}
              temp={c.current.temp_c}
              feelslike={c.current.feelslike_c}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;```
````

Este es el Actions.js

````
```import axios from "axios";
import { GET_CITY, CLOSE_CARD, ORDER_CARD } from "./types";
const apiKey = "01e86b8b56ec4c11aff162352231205";

export const getCity = (name) => {
  return async function (dispatch, getState) {
    let city = await axios.get(
      `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${apiKey}&q=${name}&aqi=no`
    );
    let newCity = city.data;
    let cities = [...getState().cities, newCity];
    // console.log(city.data);
    return dispatch({
      type: GET_CITY,
      payload: cities,
    });
  };
};

// getCity("London");

export const closeCard = (name) => {
  return {
    type: CLOSE_CARD,
    payload: name,
  };
};

export const sortCards = (value) => {
  return {
    type: ORDER_CARD,
    payload: value,
  };
};```
````

Y este es el reducer:

````
```
import { GET_CITY, CLOSE_CARD, ORDER_CARD } from "./types";

const initialState = {
  cities: [],
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CITY:
      return {
        ...state,
        cities: action.payload,
      };

    case CLOSE_CARD:
      const updatedCities = state.cities.filter(
        (c) => c.location.name !== action.payload
      );
      return {
        ...state,
        cities: updatedCities,
      };

    case ORDER_CARD:
      const sortedCities =
        action.payload === "A-Z"
          ? state.cities.sort((a, b) =>
              a.location.name.localeCompare(b.location.name, "fr", {
                ignorePunctuation: true,
              })
            )
          : state.cities.sort((a, b) =>
              b.location.name.localeCompare(a.location.name, "fr", {
                ignorePunctuation: true,
              })
            );

      return {
        ...state,
        cities: sortedCities,
      };

    default: {
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Mueve esta línea al inicio del componente `Home`, justo antes del dispatch `const [filteredCities, setFilteredCities] = useState([]);` avisanos del resultado

Comment: Lo hice pero sigue igual, si queres puedo actualizar la pregunta y le agrego la parte de redux, pero no creo que el problema esta por ahí,

Comment: comparte tu `actions`, la forma en la que se usa `filteredCities` parece buggy, se supone que `city` trae ese objeto desde el store y se esperaría que al ejecutar el reducer action `sortCards` se aplique el sort a `city` desde el reducer, se haga el re-render y se re use esta linea `const city = useSelector((state) => state.cities);` ya con el `state` modificado, entonces ese `filteredCities` pareceria estar de más, ademas de que se usa como un local state y no como parte de redux store

Comment: Ahí comparti el actions, cambiando lo del filteredCities (en donde tenías razon, no hace falta) el problema sigue

Comment: Si vos pones un console.log dentro del useEffect en que momento aparece el console?  No entiendo porque dispatch es una dependencia en ese array, nunca lo habia visto asi.

Comment: Bien no puedo emular el problema de mi lado, cuando dices `me voy a la seccion about y vuelvo al home` ¿Como haces esto?, Estas usando `react router`?

Comment: Sí, lo hago con react router, solo hago click en el boton "about", me llava a la seccion about y al volver al home las tarjetas estan acomodadas, o simplemente con hacer click en el boton home ya las acomoda.
Una solucio´n que encontre fue forzar el re-renderizado de react poniendo esta función  ```const forceUpdate = React.useReducer((bool) => !bool)[1];``` en la función handleSort.
Quedando así: ```const handleSort = (e) => {
    dispatch(sortCards(e.target.value));
    forceUpdate();
  };```.
Con esto anda bien, pero no es como debería funcionar.